# How to display related data along with node

Tags: nodes

I have a custom table that contains data related to certain nodes. I'm using EVA (Entity Views Attachment) to display some of this data along with the node, which works great.

However, I now want to display a single value from a related table when viewing a node.

I guess this could also be done using EVA, but creating a view to output a single value seems like the wrong approach(?)

In this case, the table does not contain entities. It is defined using hook_schema(), and made available to views with hook_views_data () in Drupal 7.

Thanks for any thoughts on the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

there is surprisingly many ways to acheive it :)
this is one that will require some work, but should be sane and scalable :

- in a [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7), load the data and attach it to the $node ($node->my-data)
- [optionally] in [hook_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7), create a variable for the template
- in your template file, show the value aproprietly

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Is it possible to expose the value retrieved using hook_node_load as a field under Manage Display? It's not essential, I'm just curious.

Comment: ie with [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) you can add a "code field"

Comment: this one might be even better [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)